# Insert image into documentation generated by libdoc

Tags: python, robotframework

I am currently writing a custom `Python` library for `Robot Framework`. I use  [libdoc](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/2.9.2/_modules/robot/libdoc.html) to generate documentation for it from `docstring`.

The command which I use to generate the documentation: `python -m robot.libdoc resources/pageobjects documentation.html`. Now I also want to include some screenshots in it but I didn't find any possible solution for that. If I know correctly, the docstring can be written in `reStructuredText` and with the use of it images could be inserted like this:

```
.. image:: my_screenshot.png
:height: 100px
:width: 200 px
:scale: 50 %
:alt: alternate text
:align: right
```

With this the raw text will be displayed in the documentation file. How can I achieve to include the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use rst syntax if you want, but the robot framework user guide documents how to embed images using the normal syntax for docstrings. See [Custom links and images](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#custom-links-and-images) in the section named [Documentation formatting](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#documentation-formatting) in the robot framework user guide.

The syntax is simple: `[link|content]`. If `content` is a path that ends with .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif, or .bmp, then it will be rendered as an image.

```
def some_keyword():
    """
    here is an image: [alt text|my_screenshot.png]
    """
```

If you want to use rst format, you need to tell libdoc you are using rst. You can do that by specifying the format in the library variable `ROBOT_LIBRARY_DOC_FORMAT`, or you need to supply the argument `--docformat rest` on the command line when calling libdoc. See [Documentation syntax](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#documentation-syntax) in the robot framework user guide.

Comment: The normal syntax looks nice, but I didn't find any solution in the documentation to resize the image. Is there a possibility for that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, libdoc accepts doctstring in reStrucuredText format. To use that you need to pass '--docformat rest' argument.
So your commandline should look like:

**python -m robot.libdoc --docformat rest resources/pageobjects documentation.html**

Refer: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#libdoc